# Angular4 - Routing with optional parameters and query parameters

Tags: angular, angular4-router

In angular4 routing, i am trying navigate to specific path with optional parameters but it not navigating to the correct path, Please see the below code

routes i have configured as

```
{ path:"login",component:"LoginComponent"},
 {path:"register",component:"RegisterComponent"},
 {path:"**",redirectTo:"register"}
```

i am routing to login as below
`this.router.navigate(["login",{optionalParam:"param"}])` but this is navigating to Register, i could observe in router debugging as url Redirects from "login;optionalParam=param" to "register". what could be the issue, i am facing same issue with queryParameters also.

Comment: this should work fine there is something else i guess you are missing can you create a plunker